# Git clone issue in mac systems terminal

Tags: git, terminal, ubuntu-14.04

I am facing an issue with git command on MAC system terminal while trying to execute with repo URL. Repository is stored in Phabricator itself. Issue is mentioned below.

```
Repo name (example): git clone   http://52.201.23.204/diffusion/6/ebunch_ios.git
```

when I execute the above command in MAC terminal, it does not ask me for credentials and displays a message like below.

> fatal: unable to access 'http://52.201.23.204/diffusion/7/demoproject.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

However, one more thing want to tell you in this regard that, I tried to do the same in Linux terminal and found it working properly. so facing issue only in MAC system.

- git version on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04): 1.9.1
- git version on mac: 2.4.x
- terminal version on MAC: 2.6.x

Please help me to sort it out. Please let me know if further information is required in this regard.

Thanks,

Comment: For me my mac saves my git username and password in a key-chain that is used to autologin to github and stuff. Are you sure your computer dont try to login with a invalid user/password?

Comment: Repo name (example): git clone http://52.201.23.204/diffusion/6/ebunch_ios.git
 -- the path IS EQUAL TO the path here, right? --
fatal: unable to access 'http://52.201.23.204/diffusion/7/demoproject.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: yes. it is. that path is also showing the same problem in mac terminal. both or any similar repo URL(other project) showing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

If your computer tries to autologin with a invalid password/username try to clear the osx key-chain with the following command:

```
git credential-osxkeychain erase
```

Comment: Thanks Joakim. will try it and let you know the results.